# Display message if specific button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm a newbie to javascript and web developement in general but what i'm trying to do is: create different forms and depending on which button is clicked a certain code should run( for now just display something).

Here is what i've done

```
<script>
    function init() {

      //this.onclick = showAlert;
      var p1 = document.getElementById('btn-hello');
      var p2 = document.getElementById ('btn-web');
      var p3 = document.getElementById('btn-prive');

      p1.onclick = showAlert('msghello.txt');
      p2.onclick = showAlert('msgweb.txt');
      p3.onclick = showAlert('msgprive.txt');

    function showAlert(file) {
      // Requiring fs module in which 
      // readFile function is defined.

      $.get(file, function(data) { alert(data)}, 'text');

  }
    </script>
```

[image]
The other buttons are the same just the "id" changes.

The problem is that whatever button i click it runs the code for every button.
I also tried using this argument but still does not work.

Comment: Can you please add the html for buttons also?

Comment: 1. You need to provide a function *reference*. Right now you're executing `showAlert()` when the page loads and setting the returned value (`undefined`) as the logic execute when the event happens. 2. Don't use `onclick`. Use `addEventListsner`. Here's an example: `p1.addEventlistener('click', function() { showAlert('msghello.txt'); });`. See the duplicate for more information

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thanks! One more question: where should i call that function ?

Comment: The same place you do now, just replace the entire `pN.onclick = ...` line with the example in my previous comment.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan already did but idk why when i refresh my html page it does nothing :(

Comment: Check the console for errors

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i checked and it has none, i forced refresh and still the same

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199692/discussion-between-ragingdeathwish-and-rory-mccrossan).